# Connect-PnPOnline through error "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

We have used `System.Net.WebRequest` for managing FTP files by powershell script. But, we are frequently getting "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive." whenever script try to connect with Sharepoint online by

> Connect-PnPOnline

. Any idea?

We have used below link to fix it but nothing happened..

https://blog.mamc-llc.com/2020/07/08/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-receive-when-running-wget-curl-or-invoke-webrequest-on-windows-in-powershell/
https://sharepains.com/2016/04/22/connect-pnponline-common-error-messages/
https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/issues/1566

Answer (score 0):

You may try to update your default security protocol to be TLS 1.2+ to test if it solves your issue.

[image]
Reference：

http://sharepointviews.com/the-underlying-connection-was-closed/